# displaying table on button click

Tags: javascript

I have index.jsp ,from which I am calling transaction.jsp.There is table on transaction.jsp,which i dont want to show on load of transaction.jsp,so i called a javascript method hideData() to hide the table.Now when i click on button showData on transaction.jsp,it will fetch data from database and data will be displayed in a table,which I want to display using javascript showData(),but problem is that,when i click on button,first showData() gets called and then hideData gets called as page is getting loaded again,so i am not able to diaply table on click of button.Then I tried using variable as below,but variable a is not retaining its value when it goes to hideData() after executing showData().My javascript is :
ORIGINAL POST :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var a;
    function hideData(){
        alert("a is"+a);
    alert("Inside HideData");
    if(a == " ")
    {
        alert("Inside If");
     document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display=" ";
     a= " ";
    }else{
         alert("Inside else");
         document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display="none";
         a =  "none"; 
    }
    }
    function showData(){

        document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display=" "; 
        a= " ";
    }
    </script>
```

Can anyone suggest,how i can achieve this.
Thanks in advance.
EDITED :
index.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form>
   <h2>MI Reports Data</h2>
   <a href="<s:url action="displayTransactionAction.action"/>">Transaction Data</a><br>

</s:form>
</body>
</html
```

>
transactionData.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showData(){
    document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display=" "; 
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
thead.special {
 background:url('images/mcf-header-nav.jpg') no-repeat;
 border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 3px 12px;
 margin-right: 3px 12px;
 text-align: left;
}
div.statusbar {
background:url('images/mcf-header-nav.jpg') no-repeat;
color: #fff;
width:100%
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 3px 20px;
text-align: left;
}
</style>
<title>Transaction Data</title>
<s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">


<s:form validate="true">

<div class='statusbar'>Transactions Info</div>


      <table border="true" id="dataTable" style="display:none"> 
      <thead class="special">
      <tr>
      <td >
      DateTime
      </td>
      <td>
      channel
      </td>
      <td>
      Transaction Type
      </td>
      <td>
      Bic
      </td>
      <td>
      Volume
      </td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
        <s:iterator  value="listTransBean">   
        <tbody>
             <tr>
             <td>
            <s:property value="dateTime"/><br/>
            </td>
            <td>   
            <s:property value="channel"/><br/>
            </td>
            <td>   
            <s:property value="transactionType"/><br/>
            </td>
            <td>   
            <s:property value="bic"/><br/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <s:property value="volume"/><br/>
            </td>
            </tr>     
            </tbody> 
        </s:iterator>  
        </table>
          <table>
          <tr>
          <td>
       <s:submit id="submitButton" value="Show Chart" align="center" action="displayChartAction"/>
       </td>
       <td>
       <s:submit value="Fetch Data" align="center" action="displayDataAction" onclick="showData();"/>
       </td>
       </tr>
       </table>

   </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you set style of your dataTable element to be hidden without using javascript? For example `<table style="display: none">...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.As per my understanding,using style="display: none"> will always hide my table.But I want that on page(transaction.jsp) load it should not come,but on click of button on that page(transaction.jsp),table should be displayed.

Comment: The table is initially hidden just when browser renders your page but it's not locked like that forever. You can still show its contents using javascript, e.g. your `showData()` function.

Comment: _“As per my understanding,using style="display: none"> will always hide my table”_ – that’s why you _change_ the value of `display` on click of your button …

Comment: @ghost I tried what you mentioned,but unfortunaltely,table is not getting displayed on click of button,which i believe is due to the reason that we have set hardcoded value style="display: none" in table tag,so even when we are changing value to " ",it is still taking harcoded binded value i.e none.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no such thing as hardcoded style while you're creating dynamic website. With javascript you can edit any property. You have to learn a lot about javascript. You are probably doing something wrong with your button. Provide all relevant code and I will help you.

Comment: Dear ghost..I am not sure you got me right...Please check the code .I have added index.jsp and transactionData.jsp with the javascript code u suggested.

Comment: Dear ghost..do u have any suggestion from ur vast javscript experience??

Answer (score 1):

To show data you have set display style to block..

```
document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display="block";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,but my problem is different.I want to hide table on load of transactionData.jsp and show it on click of showData button.

Comment: yes.. in showData() ypu gave as 
document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display=" "; 
so I thought if if you give as 
document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display="block"; 
it may work..

I don't know if this 
document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display=" "; 
will show the element..

I couldn't comment.. So I posted it as an answer..

Comment: since you have added hideData() function you can remove style="display:none" from the table tag..

Answer (score 0):

```
        <input type="button" onclick="registerFunc()" Value="Register"></button>
        <div id="demo" style="display: none">

            <h2 class="mainmenu">Testing DB Connection</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                @foreach(var row in db.Query(userQuery))
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@row.id</td>
                            <td>@row.email</td>
                            <td>@row.pswd</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>The time is @DateTime.Now</p>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function registerFunc() {document.getElementById('demo').style.display="block";          
    };
</script>
```

function registerFunc() {document.getElementById('demo').style.display="block";

div id="demo" style="display: none"

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try out like this below. Hope this may help you out with this to get out from the challenge you may have obviously.

```
document.getElementById("name1").style.display= "none";
document.getElementById("name2 ").style.display = "block";
```

As I have mentioned in the above first thing see the id names I meant over there like  name1, name2. Here name 1 will be the data which you not to show when you open a form or anything as per your requirement.name2 is the data you need to show up when you open the form etc..

First thing is you need use inline style use like this : style="display:none"; which one you need not to display by default. later use the condition in javascript wherever you need to override the condition applied using inline CSS property.

For an example:
HTML and CSS:

```
<table>
        <tr>

            <td class="text-center colspan-2 "><button onclick="saveEmp()"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg save"  value="Save" id="save1">Save</button></td>
            <td class="text-center colspan-2">
                <button onclick="update()"  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg save"  value="Update" id = "update1" style="display:none;" >Update</button></td>

        </tr>
        </table>
```

Javascript:
first condition:

```
 document.getElementById("save1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("update1").style.display = "none";
```

second condition I making the second data to display and making the first data not to display:

```
document.getElementById("save1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("update1").style.display = "block";

function save() { 
  document.getElementById("save1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("update1").style.display = "none";
}

function update() {    
  document.getElementById("save1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("update1").style.display = "block";
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>            
        <td class="text-center colspan-2 "><button onclick="saveEmp()"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg save"  value="Save" id="save1">Save</button></td>
        <td class="text-center colspan-2">
            <button onclick="update()"  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg save"  value="Update" id = "update1" style="display:none;" >Update</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```